# C#: What technic is that code?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know:

1. What technic is that code?
2. Can you rewrite that code to make it more readable,  because I do
   not completely understand its meaning.

   ```
   Paragraph para = CaretPosition.Paragraph;


   var matchedRun = para.Inlines.FirstOrDefault(inline =>
   {
      Run run = inline as Run;
      return (run != null && run.Text.EndsWith(inputText));
   }) as Run;


   if (matchedRun != null)
   {


   }
   ```

Comment: Posting as a comment because I only can answer (1) it's LINQ. What *do* you understand about the code?

Comment: he do not completely understand its meaning.

Comment: It would help to know what you don't understand about it.

Comment: @HPT he ??? The whole var block, but Lee made a good rewrite!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say a more readable version would be:

```
var matchedRun = para.Inlines
    .OfType<Run>()
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Text.EndsWith(intputText));
```

`OfType` filters the input sequence on the given type (Run) and `FirstOrDefault` finds the first `Run` instance whose `Text` property ends with the given input (or null if none was found).

Comment: That's neat, I hadn't come across `OfType` before.

Answer (score 3):

It's Linq. Do you know the "var" keyword? It's a type that the compiler knows but the programmer doesn't want to write.

The re-written code without using Linq is

```
Paragraph para = CaretPosition.Paragraph;

Run matchedRun = null;
foreach (var inl in para.Inlines)
{
   Run run = inl as Run;
   if( (run != null) && run.Text.EndsWith(inputText))
   {
     matchedRun = run;
     break;
   }  
}

if (matchedRun != null)
{


}
```

Note that I converted "inline" to "inl". It's not a keyword in C# but Stackoverflow makes it look like one.

Also note that it's even LESS readable once you get accustomed to Linq!

Comment: You cannot assign null to var, because compiler won't recognize the type.

Answer (score 1):

This code appears to be related to the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612650.aspx) class in the .NET Framework.

The [CaretPosition.Paragraph.Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.inlines.aspx) is a collection of "Inlines" that make up the body of the paragraph.

The code is basically looking for any `Inlines` that are of type `Run`, and setting the value of `matchedRun` to that first instance if there are any. The `FirstOrDefault` method is simply a convenient way to look inside a collection of objects and retrieve the first element or a default value if the collection is empty.

As far as readability, if you are familiar with LINQ syntax, it isn't too bad to wade through that code, though I do personally find the example code provided by [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292122/c-what-technic-is-that-code/4292147#4292147) to be a bit more readable - mostly because of the use of another LINQ expression: [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it's called "THE MIGHTY LINQ TECHNIQUE" :)

Jokes apart

it is Linq method to get the First element from the collection or return default value.

```
var matchedRun = para.Inlines.FirstOrDefault(inline =>{   Run run = inline as Run;   return (run != null && run.Text.EndsWith(inputText));}) as Run;
```

=> is called the Lambda techique for shorthand delagate decalaration

so you can read it as

Find 1st object from the para.Inlines collection where that object EndsWith some user suplied value or retrun default value if no match found

if you don't want to use this technique which actually reduces lot of code so you can try below equibvalent code

```
        Paragraph para = CaretPosition.Paragraph;
        var matchedRun = null;
        foreach (var inl in para.Inlines)
        {   Run run = inl as Run; 
            if ((run != null) && run.Text.EndsWith(inputText))
            { matchedRun = run; break; } 
        }
```

Now you can decide which is better to write